# What situations trigger Firebase push token refresh?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I'm encountering push tokens becoming invalid in a react-native project using firestore and cloud messaging. I'm just curious what triggers a push token change. a couple ive noticed:

- deleting the app and re-installing seems to trigger a new token generation
- logging in/out seems to trigger a new token also.

just wondering if anyone can provide a definitive list of things that cause a new token to be generated and an old token to expire. Not sure if this is also a function of time, haven't gotten that far in testing.

To be clear, im not referring to access tokens. this is about firebase cloud messaging tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of possible reasons can be seen in the [documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin) under the `messaging/registration-token-not-registered` error code:

> - The client app unregistered itself from FCM.
> - The client app was automatically unregistered. This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback
>     Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - The registration token expired. For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for
>     iOS devices.
> - The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages.

In general, your code should not care **why** a token became invalid.  Your client code should simply compensate for any changes by always reporting the latest token whenever the app launches, or a new token is generated using the listener provided by the client API.  For example, [onNewToken will listen to token changes on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation).  And your server code should remove any tokens where the above error message was generated.